# grab URL in php script for post

Tags: php

Good day all, I would like to know what is the correct method in PHP to grab the full URL and parameters.

I need this to check if the user is posting the url incorrectly.

Thank you to Raisen for his answer. Using

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

I was able to see the users system was hitting my link and spelling a parameter incorrectly.

Comment: Clearify your question(s) and post some example code. What have you tried?

Comment: I have clarified my question, I hope this helps.

Comment: "best" is not a good word here. We don't  like subjective questions.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QUERY_STRING element from the $_SERVER array should do the trick.

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

Or try the REQUEST_URI element:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```